# Password protection on flatpak apps

Tags: bash, scripts, flatpak

I found a bash script to password protect one of my flatpak apps but it doesn't seem to work, please tell me where I got it wrong
script->

```
#!/bin/bash
read -s -p "Enter password: " PASSWORD
flatpak run com.example.app --password="$PASSWORD"
```

now since I wanted this script to run every time I open the app, I found out that I need to do changes in the **.desktop** file of that app, so I changed the Exec line in that file accordingly

```
Exec=/home/user/scripts/password-script.sh flatpak run com.example.app
```

I tried running this, but it didn't work, is there anything that I am missing? My OS is Ubuntu 22.04 and the app is saved in the **.local/share/flatpak/app** directory since I made a user installation. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since your script is a bash script have you told the desktop file `Terminal=True`?

Comment: I dont think so i have, lemme try

Comment: @Terrance i tried it but it didnt work either

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that you are running the flatpak twice.  Once in the script and once outside the script.  You probably need to remove the call outside of the script.

Comment: Ill try that too wait